# How many 1000-bit vectors differ from any given example by fewer than 450 bits?

Tags: probability

I'm trying to follow a [coursera lesson on big data](https://class.coursera.org/bigdata-004/lecture/27), and I'm having trouble with what is offered as a trivial problem:

> Consider the space of all 1000-bit vectors. (There are $2^{1000}$ possibilities.) The average number of bits that differ, i.e. 'distance', between any two vectors is 500.
>
> Now consider a particular vector $x$ chosen at random. Obviously, half of all other vectors differ by fewer than 500 bits, half by more than 500 bits. But how many differ from $x$ by fewer than 450 bits?

1. I imagined the solution was the number of vectors that differ by 1 bit, plus the number of vectors that differ by 2 bits, and so forth up to 449 bits.
2. I imagined that the number of vectors that differed by any given number of bits $k$ was equal to the number of ways to choose $k$ bits from a group of 1000, i.e. $\frac{1000!}{k!(1000-k)!}$

$$\text{number of vectors} = \sum_{k=1}^{449} \frac{1000!}{k!(1000-k)!}$$

...but that must be wrong or there must be a way to simplify this. (My python script can't make a float out of the numbers because they're too long.) The lecture says that "only a .0007th are fewer than 450 bits from $x$."

Is my formula in error? If not, can it be reduced during calculation to exclude such huge numbers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your formula is correct, and there's no exact simplification. However, the number of differing coordinates is binomially distributed with a large $n$, so you can [approximate it using the normal distribution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution#Normal_approximation) with the same mean and standard deviation: in this case, a normal distribution with mean $500$ and standard deviation $\sqrt{250} \approx 15.8$. So a vector that differs from the original on fewer than 450 coordinates will be at least
$$
\frac{500-450}{\sqrt{250}} \approx 3.16
$$
standard deviations from the mean, which happens with a probability of roughly $0.0007$. Presumably this is where your lecturer got his numbers from...